# Gnome: How does one change directory exploration settings?

Tags: linux, gui

I am using the GUI (yes, I make heavy use of the terminal for directory traversal too) to look through some files and was wondering where do I go to change the following:

Whenever I click on a folder/directory, a new window pops up showing the directory contents rather than simply refreshing the directory explorer like I am used to.  I have not encountered this on other Linux systems before (perhaps that setting had been changed for me without my knowledge) and I would simply like to keep browsing in a single window if possible.

My system properties are as follows:

```
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
Release:    6.4
Codename:   Santiago
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Nautilus (Gnome's default file manager), there is an option for this. Go to "Edit" => "Preferences" and select the "Behavior" tab:

[image: Nautilus preferences window]

The details may be different since they will depend on which version of `nautilus` you are using. The screenshot above is of Nautilus v. 3.4.2.